# socket() failed: No buffer space available while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, 500-error, fcgi

On my ubuntu 10.04 VPS, I get a regular 500 error on nginx (0.7.??)+ fcgi web server running a durpal site and when I trace the nginx error log I see plenty of these:

> socket() failed: No buffer space
>   available) while connecting to
>   upstream ...,

I have tried differnt combination of configs but none fixed the problem. Currently I have 3 nginx workers, Keep-alive time out 15 seconds and and

PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=5
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000

I really appreciate if you Can you suggest a solution to this annoying problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably reaching your limit of RAM or of open sockets. Check the number of sockets with cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max and increase it with sysctl -w fs.file-max=[BIG NUMBER]

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the upstream server, not in nginx, but I'm
just guessing.

You can set your worker processes to 4 and then try

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and will give the feedback.

Comment: No chance Gaurav, I still get the same error

Comment: You are exhausting a kernel resource. You should provide some basic
information about what sort of system this is (is it a VPS? What OS?) etc

Comment: Sorry I added the OS info at the topic. It is ubuntu 10.04. The Linux  Kernel is 2.6.18-194

Comment: It seems to be issue with your OS which is exceeding the limit.

Comment: Comments are correct, answer is not. This is a local kernel problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add more RAM or free some system resources, to have allocable ram for system processes.

¿can you check free -mt or top, at the time that the error happens?